# Clojure and Clojure Applications don't compile with IBM SDK while compile with SUN's JRE

Tags: clojure, compilation

I am trying to migrate a clojure application from Tomcat on SUN JRE to WebSphere Application Server on IBM's SDK. The application was compiling fine (ANT) using SUN JRE 1.7 but was throwing NullPointerExceptions with IBM's SDK 6, 7.

I suspected clojure itself (v1.1 + contrib 1.1) and attempted to compile it. Again, clojure compiled with SUN's JRE but stopped with IBM's SDK at a clojure **defmacro**. I had similar results with clojure 1.2 + contrib 1.2. I don't want to go above version 1.2 because, to my understanding, that is when contrib retired and it will be a big rewrite that I doubt will fix the issue.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the line (or the name of the macro) where the exception is thrown?

Comment: does *any* of your clojure code run when using IBM's SDK?

Comment: Thanks Juan and Aurthur for getting back to me. The compilation stops at core.clj, L2019, defmacro deseq. Arthur, I couldn't get clojure lib or clojure code to compile with IBM's SDK let alone run :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to finally figure it out.

The problem is in IBM JDKs versions 6 (Although some versions of 6 might work with no problem) and 7 JIT compiler. By disabling JIT (e.g -Xnojit in the JVM arguments), I was able to build successfully.

Thank you all for your efforts and support.

============= EDIT =============

The JIT issue is fixed starting Java 7 SR4 and later. This is the SDK 7 that ships with WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5.